# Automatically resize height of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, height

I'm testing a snippet of code for an automatic iframe resize. The code is as follows:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(function(){

            var iFrames = $('iframe');

            function iResize() {

                for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                  iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
                }

                if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

                   iFrames.load(function(){
                       setTimeout(iResize, 0);
                   });

                   for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                        var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                        iFrames[i].src = '';
                        iFrames[i].src = iSource;
                   }

                } else {
                   iFrames.load(function() { 
                       this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
                   });
                }

            });

    </script>
```

The page that I'm trying to include is as follows:
http://iframe.imoti.co/index.php

The page with the iframe is: http://iframe.imoti.co/iframe.html

However, it does not seem to work. The iframe appears with zero height. I guess, the problem is with the /index.php included page. However, I do lack the knowledge to troubleshoot the issue.

Any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: There's no content on your index page. That's probably why it's loading with 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is entirely wrong.

As a Starter your selector isn't selecting the iframe class

Instead of `$("iframe")` it should be `$(".iframe")` as the `.` indicates that you are selecting a class. The same as `#` indicates that you are selecting an ID.

Your parentheses are also incorrect:

Below is a correction of your code which does display the iframe (partially) however you will need to correct your code to get it display as you want it to display.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){

        var iFrames = $('.iframe');

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
              iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
            }


            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

               iFrames.load(function(){
                   setTimeout(iResize, 0);
               });

               for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
               }

            } else {
               iFrames.load(function() { 
                   this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
               });
            }
        }        
   });
</script>
```

If you are trying to auto-resize your app I believe that you have massively over complicated the issue. Also, with regards to SEO I would highly recommend not using IFrames as there is debate as to whether search engines read IFrames and also duplicate content. However that is another issue that is beyond the scope of the question.